# Configuration of section numbering and section heading

Tags: align

I am using the `article` class (and I have to).
How could I use the command `\section{<heading>}` in such a way to produce the specific configuration as seen in the attached figure below?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

In this section, we resolve the world's all problems.

\section{Conclusion}

We resolved all the current problems of the world.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: @Mensch  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\sffamily\filleft}{\MakeUppercase{section}~\thesection}{1ex}{\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\section{Introduction}

In this section, we resolve the world's all problems.

\section{Conclusion}

We indeed resolved all the current problems of the world.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes, that's it, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`\begin{flushright}` and  `\end{flushright}` aligns text to the right margin.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\thesection}{Section \arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\begin{flushright}
\section{\break Introduction}
\end{flushright}

In this section, we resolve the world's all problems.

\begin{flushright}
\section{\break Conclusion}
\end{flushright}

We resolved all the current problems of the world.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to renew the `\section` command to output the text.

Comment: I've used the renew command in the second line of my answer.

Comment: I've aligned 'section 1' to the right.

Comment: Thank you, it now works well.